Postgres Stored Procedure - filtering table with multi condition
Hi I am trying to create procedure which filters data and returns table.
Also my column names includes double quotes (i.e "Country","date")
my code is as follows
create or replace function filter_data(filter_conditions text)
   RETURNS VOID
   language plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    v_sql text default '';
BEGIN
    V_SQL = 'CREATE TEMP TABLE TEST ON COMMIT DROP AS 
            SELECT *
            FROM schema.countrys
            where '||filter_conditions||'
            ';
            execute V_SQL;
            return;
end;
$function$

Once i run below call statement i am getting
select * from filter_data('"Country" in ('China', 'Hongkong') and "date"='2024-01-11'')

Error:
select * from filter_data('"Country" in ('China', 'Hongkong'...

Anything which needs to modify

Using double-dollar quoting: select * from filter_data($$"Country" in ('China', 'Hongkong') and "date"='2024-01-11'$$);

Thyanks, but final result that i am seeing is "Fiter_data with void , no table is returned

Yes, your function needs a revision. See my answer below.

SQL injection is so 1990s. Don't do it like this!

Your function needs not create a temporary table but rather return setof schema.countrys instead of void (see the documentation here and here).
create or replace function filter_data(filter_conditions text)
returns setof schema.countrys language plpgsql as
$function$
DECLARE
  v_sql text;
BEGIN
  v_sql = 'SELECT * FROM schema.countrys WHERE ' || filter_conditions;
  return query execute v_sql;
END;
$function$;

Please note that this function is dangerously SQL injection prone.

The goal of the function is to facilitate SQL injection, it's injecting unknown filter_conditions. Pretty sure this will end in a disaster. Just test true; delete from countrys returning * to see the results (Advice: Make a backup first!)
